# How much perfume should I wear at work?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, ethics, dress-code

I know it is not professional to wear perfume at work, but I recently bought a bottle of perfume. Is there a way I can use it professionally?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etiquette and cultural norms rather than a workplace-specific issue.

Answer (score 6):

A quick search shows that there is a lot of recommendations against perfume, or against strong perfumes. For example, [From Forbes.](http://www.forbes.com/sites/leahbourne/2012/02/07/should-you-wear-perfume-to-work/):

> A general rule of thumb when it comes to wearing perfume at work—go scent free at job interviews. For those already in a job, check to see if your office has a fragrance policy. If it doesn’t, opt for something on the lighter side for the workday. Just like with fashion, leave experimentation for when you are off the clock.

[Also, be aware that perfume can trigger migraines, and may be banned in your workplace for legal and disability reasons.](http://www.healthcentral.com/migraine/c/11175/67623/disabilities-act/) So I'd recommend erring on the side of caution where possible, and only wear perfume if you are sure your workplace explicitly allows it.